# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . when setting values to firebase database

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set values to my firebase realtime database and I have the following code for that. It should work, but it does not. All I can get is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

On every if statement line. I am not sure why is this happening.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId +"/settings").set({
  if (publicCountryYes.checked) {
    publicCountryFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicCountryFirebase: false;
  };
  if (publicCompanyYes.checked){
    publicCompanyFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicCompanyFirebase: false;
  };
  if (publicEmailYes.checked){
    publicEmailFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicEmailFirebase: false;
  };
  if (publicInterestsYes.checked){
    publicInterestsFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicInterestsFirebase: false;
  };

  if (publicNameYes.checked){
    publicNameFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicNameFirebase: false;
  };
  if (publicPhoneYes.checked){
    publicPhoneFirebase: true;
  }else{
    publicPhoneFirebase: false;
  };
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an object with each keys values set based on a conditional? Like this? `set({ publicEmailFirebase: publicEmailYes, etc... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is invalid, I'd suggest you can use something more concise:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId + "/settings").set({
    publicCountryFirebase: publicCountryYes.checked,
    publicCompanyFirebase: publicCompanyYes.checked
    // etc
});
```